# Find the general solution of $y'=\frac{-2}{y}-\frac{3y}{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution to the following first order differential equation:

$$y'=-\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3y}{2x}$$

I've tried using various substitutions but these don't seem to be helping. Can anyone suggest how to start this?

Comment: set $$y=xu$$ to solve the equation, it is a Bernoulli equation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
y'=-\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3y}{2x}&&\\
2xyy'+4x+3y^2&=&0\\
x(y^2)'+4x+3(y^2)&=&0\hspace{2cm}(y^2=u)\\
u'+\frac{3}{x}u&=&-4
\end{eqnarray}
which is a differential equation of first order.